SvelteKit: Slug Route within a Group Route
I have this SvelteKit directory setup: routes/(main)/vergabeassistent.
Within that directory I have:

+page.svelte
[slug]/+page.svelte

Calling localhost:5173/vergabeassistent works fine and is a list view. I now wanted to create slug route for the detail view and the id is a parameter in the url. However, calling localhost:5173/vergabeassistent/SOMEID is not being found at all. I suspect this may be caused by the fact that I am already withhin a the group route of (main)?
The +page.svelte of the slug route looks like this:
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from './$types';

    export let data: PageData;
</script>

<h1>{data}</h1>

What am I doing wrong?

You haven't named the file [slug]/+page.svelte, right? You have created a sub-folder named [slug], which then in turn contains a file named +page.svelte right?

Correct [slug] is a directory.

I don't think using groups has anything to do with this. I don't see any error at all. But maybe when you created the sub-folder and file ([slug]/+page.svelte) you entered some weird/hidden character? Try deleting them and create them anew (without copy-pasting their names). Because Vite sends back 404, right?

There were no weird hidden characters. Our svelte FE is behind a Routing-Proxy that allows running our BE on the same port. That would be my only remaining guess of what the cause is.

Do you have a matching [slug]/+page.ts that implements a load function and returns the data (assumedly based on the value of the slug parameter) you are expecting? Silly question but it's not mentioned in your question.

is not being found at all means that you get back 404 from Vite, right?

There is a trailing slash option you can look into, but based on the info you have provided, I don't see how this can be the cause of it.

@PeppeL-G Yes, I get a 404 from Vite.
@Thomas Hennes No I do not, the page is just an h1 tag.  I tried completely empty pages too to not success.

@PeppeL-G I will try the trailing slash option when I am back at work.

It turned out to not have anything todo with svelte but the Quinoa/Quarkus stack we use that doesnt allow this to work at all: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-quinoa/issues/591
